# How to get all data of the table in all pages of the website?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, export-to-csv

There is this web page in APS, and there is a table showing the translations of words (10 words in each column) both in English and Persian. I am trying to write a code with Python (Pandas or any useful module) to get all the data from the table on every page and build a single table that contains all 
the words and their translations on all pages in two columns in a CSV file. 
Below the table there are page numbers beginning from 1-2123. Is it possible to write a code and copy only the table on every page to a CSV (preferably with "|" as delimiter)? link = "http://update.dotic.ir/eLibrary/frmDictionary.aspx"

Comment: I am confused how to introduce every page to a loop, since the page is in asp and the links for all pages are the same!

Answer (score 0):

In order to get info from web you can use selenium or urllib module.
Afterwards you can parse html with bs4 python library without "creating" any loops.